# cordova sqlite - order of columns

Tags: android, ios, sqlite, cordova

I am using sqlite in a Cordova app. I am generating the tables dynamically on an html page to view the data being stored in it. However, when viewing this html page on an android tablet, I am able to view the columns in the order they are supposed to be in the database but in the iOS the order of the columns in the tables seem to be different from the placement in the database. I am not sure why this is happening but it makes for a less user friendly viewing. I expect the tables in the database to have columns in proper order so my guess was that this was happening when executing the SELECT statements but I am not 100% sure about it.

Is there any way to fix this or has anyone else faced this error as well? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

**EDIT: The following are the CREATE and INSERT statements that I use to create the tables and insert the data. They seem to be working as expected, as far as I know**

CREATE TABLE STATEMENT

```
// Dynamic Function to create table
function createTable(tableName, columns) {
    myDB.transaction(function(transaction) {
        // Create column arrays
        var columnNames = [];
        for (var i=0; i<columns.length; i++){
            columnNames[i] = columns[i];
        }
        // Produce create query
        var columnNamesQuery = "";
        for (var i=0; i<columnNames.length; i++){
            if(i==0){
                columnNamesQuery = columnNamesQuery + columnNames[i];
            } else{
                columnNamesQuery = columnNamesQuery + ", " + columnNames[i];
            }
        }
        // Create query
        var query = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ' + tableName + ' (' + columnNamesQuery + ')';
        transaction.executeSql(query, [],
        function(tx, result) {
            //navAlert("Table " + tableName + " created successfully");
        },
        function(error) {
             navAlert("Error occurred while creating table:" + JSON.stringify(error));
        });
    });
}

// Function Lists
function createTableProjects() {
    var columnNames = ["projectUID text PRIMARY KEY","projectName text","projectType text","projectLocation text","projectDescription text","projectStartDate text","projectStopDate text","optionalQ1 text","optionalQ2 text","optionalQ3 text","optionalQ4 text","optionalQ5 text","optionalQ6 text"];
    createTable("tblprojects",columnNames);
}
```

INSERT STATEMENT

```
function insertIntoTable(table, columns, data) {
    // Column Name Query String
    var columnNamesQuery = "(";
    for (var i=0; i<columns.length; i++){
        if(i==0){
            columnNamesQuery = columnNamesQuery + columns[i];
        }else{
            columnNamesQuery = columnNamesQuery + ", " + columns[i];
        }
    }
    columnNamesQuery = columnNamesQuery + ")";

    // Column Name Value String
    var query = "";
    myDB.transaction(function(transaction) {
        var primary_id = "";
        for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
            var row = data[i];
            // Create insert query
            var columnValuesArray = [];
            var columnValuesQuery = "(";
            for(var j=0; j<columns.length; j++){
                var val = row[columns[j]];
                if(j==0){
                    primary_id = val;
                }
                if(val === undefined || val == null){
                    val = "";
                }
                columnValuesArray[j] = val;
                if(j<columns.length-1){
                    columnValuesQuery = columnValuesQuery + "?,";
                } else if(j==columns.length-1){
                    columnValuesQuery = columnValuesQuery + "?)";
                }
            }

            // Insert query
            var project_query = 'INSERT OR REPLACE INTO ' + table + columnNamesQuery + ' VALUES ' + columnValuesQuery + ";";
            transaction.executeSql(project_query, columnValuesArray,
                function(tx,result){
                    //navAlert("Data inserted/replaced in table: " + table);
                },
                function(error) {
                    navAlert("Error: " + return_val + " " + project_query);
                }
            );
        }
    });
}

// Inserted in tablet on download from server
function insertTblProjects(dataArray){
    var columns = ["projectUID","projectName","projectType","projectLocation","projectDescription","projectStartDate","projectStopDate","optionalQ1","optionalQ2","optionalQ3","optionalQ4","optionalQ5","optionalQ6"];
    insertIntoTable("tblprojects",columns, dataArray);
}
```

Comment: Can you show us how you append the results of the database query to the table?

Comment: @forgetaboutme Just added the functions I use to create and insert statements